# How to stop all p:poll with event onclick button

Tags: primefaces

Example, i have 20 charts. there are have time refresh different. When `updateChart`, i'll dosomething and update success.

```
<c:foreach var="chart" items="#{bean.charts}>
  <p:poll interval="#{chart.timeRefresh}" listener="#{bean.updateChart(chart)}"/>
  <div>..draw one-by-one chart here.</div>
</c:foreach>
<p:commandButton id="showInforDialog" actionlistener="#{bean.dosomething()}" onsuccess="PF('dlgInfor').show();"/>
```

for example, alls chart have same time refresh and equal 1s. when i click button `btnStopAllPoll` will call `dosomething()` and will show dialog, but I have to wait a very long time. I think 20 request are processed in turn.
i have one idea, create `button` and `onclick` will stop all poll i tried :

```
<p:commandButton id="stoppAllPoll" onclick="stopAllPoll()"/>
```

but I do not know how to do it. please help me! or you have new idea.
i don't understand why 20 request are processed in turn, or I'm wrong

Comment: PrimeFaces does not have a pool component. There IS a poll component. Regarding the actual question, that is a bit unclear to me can you clarify

Answer (score 2):

First of all, poll Ajax actions are executed synchronically by default. So if you execute 20 actions, they are queued and executed one at a time. That might take a while and explains the delay you are experiencing. Set the `async` attribute of the `p:poll` component to `true` to prevent this.

Then, why use 20 polls in the first place? Isn't is much cleaner to just use 1 poll? You can specify multiple components that need to be updated, even by using a [selector](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml). This will also prevent you from running out of the number of connections the client or possibly even the server can handle simultaneously.

If you do want to stop multiple polls, use `widgetVar="pollXxx"` so you can stop them using JavaScript:

```
PF('poll1').stop();
PF('poll2').stop();
...
```

Comment: Ah... makes sense now. No idea why I missed this. I personally would not even use polling but push and with a small random delay on the client (e.g. if there are many clients watching the charts) update them

Comment: Even if you set async to true, most likely you are limited by the number of simultaneous requests a browser can/will do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: Good point. It is far from efficient in many ways. I would opt to simply use one poll and update multiple components.

Comment: in my case, the number of chart is dynamic 10,15,20 or more. there are have time refresh different.
ex: chart1: 3s, chart2: 5s, chart3: 10s....
so, i can't just use 1 poll. in here, i'm using <o:socket> of omnifaces.

Comment: @TrươngHuy your question states "all chart have same time refresh and equal 1s".